# Binding DropDownList from Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm building a view which will display tabular data based on selections from two dropdownlists, the first which selects departments is populated from the database. The second is a static dropdownlist for "Year" which I haven't got to yet. There are answers to similar questions, but I've looked at them and tried everything. I've got to the point where I'm getting a null exception in the view where I created the markup for the dropdownlist.

**View:**

Departments is coming back as null. I'm new to MVC and pieced this together from online [examples](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/asp-net-mvc-populating-dropdown-lists-in-razor-views-using-the-mvvm-design-pattern-entity-framework-and-ajax). I'm guessing my model is wrong.

```
@model IEnumerable<BudgetDemo.Models.BudgetsActualsViewModel>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => item.Departments, 
        new SelectList(item.Departments.Select(x => x.Text)))
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public class BudgetsActualsViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Cost Center/Department")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Cost Center/Department is required.")]
    [StringLength(62)]
    public string SelectedDepartment { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Departments { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult GetBudgetsActuals()   
{
    repo = new BudgetDemoRepository();
    ModelState.Clear();
    return View(repo.GetBudgetsActuals());
}
```

**Repository Class:**

```
public List<BudgetsActualsViewModel> GetBudgetsActuals()  
{
    ...
    List<BudgetsActualsViewModel> budgetsActualsList = new List<BudgetsActualsViewModel>();
    // Query returning correct data from DB here

    for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        budgetsActualsList.Add(
            new BudgetsActualsViewModel
             {
                 SelectedDepartment = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Department"].ToString()
             }
        );
    }
    return budgetsActualsList;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried copying the values in another list instead passing the list that the method is returning?

Comment: @JamshaidKamran, no because to be honest, I don't understand why I have two properties for my drop down ( I copied that from linked example) and got an IEnumerable cast exception when I tried.

Comment: Okay, it is clear. You are saving the values in `SelectedDepartment`, and accessing the other property which obviously would be null.

Comment: Your `BudgetsActualsViewModel` class has `Departments` defined as type `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`, while your repository's is returning type `List<BudgetsActualsViewModel>` for the method `GetBudgetsActuals()`

Comment: @JamshaidKamran, agreed. But I need a code sample as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: @IrishChieftain, I have shared a solution as an answer. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, You are saving the values in `SelectedDepartment` property and accessing the `Departments` list. Which is never initialized so it would obviously be `null`.

Modify your `GetBudgetsActuals` method like this:

```
public BudgetsActualsViewModel GetBudgetsActuals()  
{
    ...
    BudgetsActualsViewModel budgetsActuals = new BudgetsActualsViewModel(){ Departments = new List<SelectListItem>() };
    // Query returning correct data from DB here

    for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        budgetsActuals.Departments
                      .Add(new SelectListItem 
                          { 
                              Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Department"].ToString(), 
                              Value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["YourRowId"].ToString() 
                          });
    }
    return budgetsActuals;
}
```

And this is how your View should look like:

```
@model BudgetDemo.Models.BudgetsActualsViewModel
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedDepartment, Model.Departments))
```

Notice, we got rid of the `foreach` loop. We need `DropDownListFor()` method to be called only once.

---

**UPDATE**

```
public class BudgetsActualsViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Cost Center/Department")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Cost Center/Department is required.")]
    [StringLength(62)]
    public string SelectedDepartment { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Departments { get; set; } // Modify it to list instead IEnumerable.
}
```

Comment: 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' does not contain a definition for 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'

Comment: Please change your model to have a list instead `IEnumerable`. See the update.

Comment: For "YourRowId" I inserted "SelectedDepartment" and got error:  System.ArgumentException: Column 'SelectedDepartment' does not belong to table Table

Comment: @IrishChieftain, that is what you have to feed it. Your Database has an ID column which most of the cases is a primary key. Feed that column

Comment: I did that and changed the markup to @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedDepartment, Model.Departments)).
It worked, thanks Jamshaid! Much appreciated.

Comment: Quick question. I will be generating a table of data in this view. Can I do this without the IEnumerable version of my model?

Comment: Well, that needs to be descriptive to be answered. So, it must go as a new question.

Comment: It was already part of the question. "

I'm building a view which will display tabular data based on selections from two dropdownlists"

Comment: But not as descriptive as the main part of the question. I am actually not able to fully understand how the tabular data would be and how are you expecting it to look.

Comment: I will have to loop thru the Model. Since I can only use one model in a view, perhaps use a partial view for the table data based on the dropdown selection?

Comment: You might want to modify the model to have other data in it.

Comment: when I submit the form, Model.Departments is null in the View?

Comment: When the form is being posted you wouldn't need all the departments back because you already have them in your database. You just need to know which one the user had selected. The selected department should be in the `SelectedDepartment`.

Comment: In view on postback, m => m.SelectedDepartment error is "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'object' because it is not a delegate type". Error is on client, not reaching controller.

Comment: Try to use this overload of the method: `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => x.SelectedDepartment, Model.Departments, "Select Department", new { @class = "form-control" })`

Comment: CS0122: 'x' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: my bad, replace `x` with `m`.

Comment: Same markup as before. Getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" in the browser. Getting the lambada expression error when adding a quick watch while debugging.

Comment: This usually works but can't be sure what the problem is, you need to debug the problem as you can see the scenario.

Comment: I will post it as a new question. I have debugged it as much as I can. It's throwing a null reference section on the client when submitting the form. Thanks :)

Comment: New question posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64989958/posting-back-dropdownlist-from-strongly-typed-view
Appreciate all your help Jamshaid.