# Posting Back DropDownList from Strongly Typed View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

This is related to an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64977757/binding-dropdownlist-from-database) on binding a dropdownlist from a database. The dropdownlist is being bound and populated but is throwing an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error in the browser when submitting the form.

When debugging, I added a quick watch on the m => m.SelectedDepartment parameter of the Html.DropDownListFor(...) helper method and got: "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'object' because it is not a delegate type".

**View:**

```
@model BudgetDemo.Models.BudgetsActualsViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("GetBudgetsActuals", "BudgetsActuals", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedDepartment, Model.Departments, 
        "Select Department", new { @class = "form-control" })
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public class BudgetsActualsViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Cost Center/Department")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Cost Center/Department is required.")]
    [StringLength(62)]
    public string SelectedDepartment { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Departments { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
// GET: Render view with dropdowns
public ActionResult GetBudgetsActuals()
{
    repo = new BudgetDemoRepository();
    ModelState.Clear();

    try
    {                
        return View(repo.GetBudgetsActuals());
    }
    catch
    {
        return View("Error");
    }
}
```

**Repository:**

```
public BudgetsActualsViewModel GetBudgetsActuals()
{
    ...
    BudgetsActualsViewModel budgetsActuals = new BudgetsActualsViewModel() 
        { Departments = new List<SelectListItem>() };
    
    // Query returning correct data from DB here

    for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        budgetsActuals.Departments.Add(                    
            new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Department"].ToString(),
                Value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ListValue"].ToString()
            }
        );
    }

    return budgetsActuals;
}
```

**UPDATE**

It's working now. The following code was updated/added to get the form re-rendering after a postback with a success message containing the value of the selected department.

**View:**

```
@model BudgetDemo.Models.BudgetsActualsViewModel
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

@using (Html.BeginForm("GetBudgetsActuals", "BudgetsActuals",  
    FormMethod.Post))
{
     @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

     @if (TempData["SuccessMessage"] != null)
     {
         <p class="alert alert-success"
             id="successMessage">@TempData["SuccessMessage"]</p>
     }

    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedDepartment, Model.Departments, 
        "Select Department", new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedDepartment, "", 
        new { @class = "text-danger" })    
}
```

**Controllers:**

```
// GET
public ActionResult GetBudgetsActuals()
{
    Populate Department dropdown from DB and Year dropdown (static) here
    repo = new BudgetDemoRepository();
    //ModelState.Clear();

    try
    {
        return View(repo.GetBudgetsActuals());
    }
    catch
    {
        return View("Error");
    }
}

// POST
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetBudgetsActuals(BudgetsActualsViewModel model)
{
    try
    {
        repo = new BudgetDemoRepository();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            TempData["SuccessMessage"] = "Value of SelectedDepartment is: " 
                + model.SelectedDepartment;
            return View(repo.GetBudgetsActuals(model));
        }
        else
        {
            model.Departments = repo.GetBudgetsActuals().Departments;
            return View(model);
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return View("Error");
    }
}
```

**Repository** - New overloaded method to handle POST

```
public BudgetsActualsViewModel GetBudgetsActuals(BudgetsActualsViewModel model)
{
    ....
    // Get the data again
    ....
 
    budgetsActuals.SelectedDepartment = model.SelectedDepartment;
    for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        budgetsActuals.Departments.Add(
            new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Department"].ToString(),
                Value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ListValue"].ToString()
            }
         );
     }   
     return budgetsActuals;
}
```

Comment: You need to have a post method in the control that will accept a model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the `controller` to have a new api that supports a `POST` call. Do as follows.

Add this method a get method that is called when the view is loaded, like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetBudgetsActuals()
{
    repo = new BudgetDemoRepository();
    ModelState.Clear();

    try
    {                
        return View(repo.GetBudgetsActuals());
    }
    catch
    {
        return View("Error");
    }
}
```

Add a post method that is called when the form is submitted:

```
[HttpPost] // Decorate with this attribute
public ActionResult PostBudgetsActuals(BudgetDemo.Models.BudgetsActualsViewModel model)
{
    var selectedDepartment = model.SelectedDepartment;
   // dostuff with the model
   return somethingFromHere;
}
```

And change the view like this:

```
@model BudgetDemo.Models.BudgetsActualsViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("PostBudgetsActuals", "BudgetsActuals", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedDepartment, Model.Departments, 
        "Select Department", new { @class = "form-control" })
}
```

---

If you are getting an issue with the overload of `DropDownListFor` method, then you can also try `DropDownList` method like below:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("PostBudgetsActuals", "BudgetsActuals", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.DropDownList("SelectedDepartment", Model.Departments,
        "Select Department", new { @class = "form-control" })
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

```
// POST
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetBudgetsActuals(BudgetsActualsViewModel model)
{
    try
    {
        repo = new BudgetDemoRepository();
        if (model.SelectedDepartment != null)
        { 
            TempData["SuccessMessage"] = "Value of SelectedDepartment is:
                " + model.SelectedDepartment;
        }
        model.Departments = repo.GetBudgetsActuals().Departments;
        return View(model);
     }
     catch
     {
         return View("Error");
     }
}
```

Comment: In the controller, when I return View("GetBudgetsActuals") it throws the same error in the dropdownlist as before: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

When debugging I am getting a value for SelectedDepartment in the controller on postback. Your update didn't work. Still working on your original answer because at least now controller is being reached. It's just same null ref error as before when I return that view.

Comment: @IrishChieftain, When you return `View("GetBudgetsActuals")` it means you are not sending your data to your view, you are just telling the view that hey, Look out for a view named `GetBudgetsActuals` and that's it. If you pass the model in it instead a string which is taken as a viewName, then it will have the data.

Comment: "The view 'PostBudgetsActuals' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations". It's looking in BudgetsActuals folder for view named 'PostBudgetsActuals' but view is called GetBudgetsActuals.cshtml.

Comment: It is not a view, it is an api controller handling your post calls.

Comment: Your form will post this data from your current view. It should be mentioned in the `BeginForm`

Comment: I got it working and will append the updated code in the question shortly. Only problem I'm having now is that validation is not working. If I don't select an item in the dropdownlist and click Submit, I get the null reference error in the view markup again. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can always use `ModelState.IsValid` property to see if there were validation errors with the model.

Comment: ModelState is not valid on the postback and I'm not sure why. See update for details.

Comment: I got validation working in the POST controller by removing the check for the model state. It's not needed since I am re-hydrating the model. Please take a look and let me know if you think everything is correct?

Comment: It is fine, that will display the user a custom message from `ViewData`. But, `ModelState` is more elegant in getting the errors because it will compare everything that you have specified in the Model class of yours i.e `[StringLength(62)]` if it exceeds 62 then it will tell you that it has validation errors.

Comment: And imagine, if you have tens of other properties with validation rules specified with decorative attributes, then it would be easier to use `ModelState.IsValid` instead going ahead and comparing every property manually.

Comment: The problem is that both model properties are null when I check the ModelState in the POST controller. So when I add a check to see if ModelState is valid, it throws the null reference error in the browser when it hits the DropDownListFor method?

Comment: You will have to reload the Departments again, we are just getting the `SelectedDepartment` property back rest of the data gets flushed off. And when it loads the view again it again expects you to feed the list.

Comment: Could you update your answer to show me where and how I can do that in the code?

Comment: See the update, let me know if it solves your problem.

Comment: That worked. "The repo.GetBudgetsActuals().Departments;" syntax is really slick! I also took your suggestion to check the ModelState instead of checking model properties piecemeal. Thanks again Jamshaid :)

Comment: Happy to help :)